# How to initilize an optional Task and Task<T> using C#?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task

How to optionally create multiple tasks and execute them using `await Task.WhenAll(a,b,c);`

I have the following class

```
public class TaskProcessor
{
    private ProcessResult Result;

    public TaskProcessor(ProcessResult result)
    {
        Result = result ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(result));
    }

    public async Task<ProcessResult> Process(TaskOption option)
    {
        // First optional task
        Task<int?> typeFetcher = Task.FromResult<int?>(null);
        if (option is IProcessType t)
        {
            typeFetcher = t.GetAsync();
        }

        // Second optional task
        Task<int?> subtypeFetcher = Task.FromResult<int?>(null);
        if (option is IProcessSubtype st)
        {
            subtypeFetcher = st.GetAsync();
        }

        // Third optional task
        Task mainContent = Task.CompletedTask;

        if(Result.Content != null) 
        {
            mainContent = SetMainContentAsync(Result.Content);
        }

        await Task.WhenAll(typeFetcher, subtypeFetcher, mainContent);

        Result.TypeId = typeFetcher.Result,
        Result.SubtypeId = subtypeFetcher.Result;

        return result;
    }
}
```

I want to initialize the task to a default value that does nothing. As you can see in the above code, the `typeFetcher` task is initialized using `Task.FromResult<int?>(null);` and when the given `TaskOption` implements `IProcessType` interface, the task is overridden using a custom task. The same scenario implies for the `subtypeFetcher` task.

For the `mainContent` task, I initialized it using a `Task.CompletedTask` and when `Result.Content` is not null, I set the `mainContent` to `SetMainContentAsync(Result.Content)`. Finally, I await all tasks using `await Task.WhenAll(typeFetcher, subtypeFetcher, mainContent)`.

The [ASP.NET Core Performance Best Practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/performance-best-practices?view=aspnetcore-3.1) states the following

> **Do not**: Block asynchronous execution by calling `Task.Wait` or `Task.Result`.

Since I am using `Task.FromResult<int?>(null);` to initialize the tasks, I feel that I am violating best practices. I would like to learn the correct approach to initialize an optional task.

**Question** What is the correct approach to initialize an optional task that returns type? Also, is initializing a task that does not return anything to `Task.CompletedTask` acceptable or is there a more correct approach?

Comment: Review note: `option is IProcessType t` can only be true if `option` is not `null`, so the `t != null` test is superfluous.

Comment: @madreflection thanks for that tip! I update the code for simplicity

Comment: "Since I am using Task.FromResult<int?>(null); to initialize the tasks, I feel that I am violating best practices. I would like to learn the correct approach to initialize an optional task." is very confusing statement... Not sure how it relates to previous quote either...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are doing is fine. `Task.FromResult` is not `Task.Result`, the two are entirely unrelated.

`Task.Result` is an instance property that blocks the current thread until the task completes, and returns the result of the task.

`Task.FromResult` is a static method that returns a trivial, already completed task.

Answer (score 1):

First things first: using `.Result` the way you are is "ok" because you already made sure it's complete by using `await Task.WhenAll`. Your code won't be sitting at `.Result` waiting for the result and blocking the thread. But I say "ok" in quotes because of the way exceptions are handled. When you use `.Result`, exceptions are always put inside of an `AggregateException` and you have to look inside to find the real exception.

However, you can still use `await` with completed tasks, and exceptions are thrown as you'd expect:

```
Result.TypeId = await typeFetcher;
```

As to the rest of the question: the best way I find to await multiple, optional tasks is to use a `List<Task>` and just add the tasks that are needed.

```
var taskList = new List<Task>();
```

However, this is complicated by the fact that you need to use the return values from the tasks. There are a couple ways to go about it. You can use a list that you await, but also keep a reference to each task itself as you already were. Initialize the `Task` to `null` and only set the value if it's not `null`. For example:

```cs
var taskList = new List<Task>();

Task<int?> typeFetcher = null;
if (option is IProcessType t)
{
    typeFetcher = t.GetAsync();
    taskList.Add(typeFetcher);
}

...

await Task.WhenAll(taskList);

if (typeFetcher != null)
{
    Result.TypeId = await typeFetcher;
}

...
```

But you keeping two references to the same thing is... I don't know. Seems like it could be done better.

Another option is to use [local functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions) that set the value and add that to your task list. That way, you don't have to set the values after awaiting.

```cs
public async Task<ProcessResult> Process(TaskOption option)
{
    var taskList = new List<Task>();

    // First optional task
    if (option is IProcessType t)
    {
        // Declare a local function that sets the value
        async Task TypeFetcher()
        {
            Result.TypeId = await t.GetAsync();
        }

        // Call it and add the resulting Task to the list
        taskList.Add(TypeFetcher());
    }

    // Second optional task
    Task<int?> subtypeFetcher = Task.FromResult<int?>(null);
    if (option is IProcessSubtype st)
    {
        async Task SubtypeFetcher()
        {
            Result.SubtypeId = await st.GetAsync();
        }
        taskList.Add(SubtypeFetcher());
    }

    // Third optional task
    if(Result.Content != null) 
    {
        //don't need a local function here since there's no return value
        taskList.Add(SetMainContentAsync(Result.Content));
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(taskList);

    //I assume you actually declared and set result somewhere
    return result;
}
```

I'm not saying that's any more efficient than keeping two references to each `Task`. Just do what you find least confusing.